# Is it possible to create a new Hangouts on Air broadcast/stream from the API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-hangouts, youtube-livestreaming-api, hangouts-api

Is it possible to initialize a new Hangouts on Air broadcast/stream directly from the API? I'm attempting to use Hangouts on Air for my website's live broadcast system, but I don't see any API methods in the YouTube Live API that allows stream creation via Hangouts on Air (it looks like it needs a custom video source). If this isn't possible, is there a way to use a Google button to initialize the Hangout on Air, and then embed it on a webpage in real time (without having a pre-defined stream)?

I know there's live streaming protocols such as OBS, but that obviously is very intensive on a server. It's more convenient to use Google's massive infrastructure for this specific case (which I cannot talk too much about).

Comment: The API in question has shut down: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq

Comment: @balupton this question is from 2015.

Comment: Correct. It still shows up for people searching how to do it. The modern replacement is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37979700/130638

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Hangouts API is separate from the YouTube Live Streaming API.

The Hangouts API documentation is available [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/).

From your question, it sounds like you're specifically looking to use Google's [Google+ Hangout button](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button).

From the docs:

> The Hangout button lets you launch a Google+ Hangout directly from
>   your site. When you use the button, you can set up the Hangout in a
>   variety of configurations. For example, you can specify Hangout apps
>   that launch along with the Hangout and setup the Hangout as a regular
>   Hangout or a Hangout On Air.

Full On-Air API Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair).

Answer (score 2):

You can use various links to create a HoA, but none will embed it on a webpage in realtime. You could, however develop a Hangout Extension that you, as the Host, would load to do this. Here are some important things for a todo list:

1. Create a Handler for [gapi.hangout.onair.onBroadcastingChanged](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.onBroadcastingChanged) or create a function to look for YouTubeID and react when called to...
2. PING your special PHP/ASP/[whatever] server with the YouTubeID for the video (using [gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId))
3. Have your special PHP page update your special landing page via some app/server variable

Hope this helps!