# Is it possible to create event of type "Quick (using Google Hangouts On Air)" using YouTube Live Streaming API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, google-hangouts, youtube-livestreaming-api, hangouts-api

As the [Google+ Hangouts API has shut down](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq), how can I create a YouTube Live Event of type **Quick (Google Hangouts On Air)** using the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started)?

Comment: "Is it possible" is not a great question - nearly anything is possible when writing code with enough time and effort.  To enhance your question; show what code you tried and what challenges you have with it so we may assist you in fixing it.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - not sure it's obvious but... this question was asked 5 1/2 years ago. It should just be close-voted at this point, as it's obsolete now (even with the follow-up comments nearly 3 years ago, which I just flagged for removal), and it's really a documentation-request question at its core...

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to create an event of type "Quick (using Google Hangouts On Air)" using the YouTube Live Streaming API. The YouTube Live Streaming API does not support the creation of Google Hangouts On Air events.

Google Hangouts On Air is a deprecated feature that is no longer supported by Google. The YouTube Live Streaming API was introduced as a replacement for Google Hangouts On Air, and it does not support the same features.

If you need to create a live event that can be watched on YouTube, you can use the YouTube Live Streaming API to create a regular live event. You can then use a third-party service to create a Google Hangouts On Air event and link it to your YouTube live event.

Here are some third-party services that you can use to create Google Hangouts On Air events:

```
Restream: https://restream.io/
StreamYard: https://streamyard.com/
OBS Studio: https://obsproject.com/
```

These services allow you to create a Google Hangouts On Air event and then link it to your YouTube live event. This will allow your viewers to watch your live event on both YouTube and Google Hangouts On Air.

Comment: this gives me chatgpt vibes

Comment: Please add the source that supports the claim that the referred services can create **Google Hangouts On Air events** when this answer was posted in September 2023.