# How can we have a YouTube Live event communicate to our server once the Hangouts API goes away?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

Following the migration of Hangouts on Air to Youtube Live events:

["Start a Hangout on Air" button for Youtube LiveStreaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233393/start-a-hangout-on-air-button-for-youtube-livestreaming-api)

It seems that the hangouts API is not being retired on April 25th

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq

with hangouts being more focused on the "enterprise".  This is going to cause various of our enterprise's critical applications to stop working.  Google Enterprise support indicates that something may come along to replace the hangouts API.

Does anyone have any leads on this replacement? We'd very much like to start working with an alternative well in advance of April 25th.

Is anyone aware of any mechanism to allow a YouTube Live event (hangout type) to communicate back to a 3rd party server to indicate it's status and participants?

Many thanks in advance

Related Post:

[Is it possible to create event of type "Quick (using Google Hangouts On Air)" using YouTube Live Streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979700/is-it-possible-to-create-event-of-type-quick-using-google-hangouts-on-air-us)

Comment: The official docs you've provided confirms that the Hangouts API is being retired although some features will stick through. I'm looking for confirmation whether Hangouts air buttons will remain but couldnt find one. Try the Send Feedback form on the FAQs page to inquire about this.

Comment: thanks noogui - I've been asking on youtube forums and through google enterprise support - no one seems to be willing to say anything for sure - but google enterprise support indicate there's a possibility of a replacement, but apparently can't tell me anything more ...