# YouTube v3 api : How to start a hangout video recording?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, live-streaming, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a YouTube live stream using v3 api and `node.js`, and I've followed [life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) tutorial to start a live broadcast.

So after the insertion, streaming and binding there appears a event on my channel according to the parameters I passed into the API request. When I go to the live control, I see a message in red saying..

> We are not receiving data from your encoder. Please make sure it is
>   configured correctly in the Ingestion Settings page.

My question is that how do I start recording with hangouts? Where will the **hangouts screen** appear? Do I need to call some hangouts API?

Any guesses?

Comment: Looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233393/start-a-hangout-on-air-button-for-youtube-livestreaming-api), I think you will get bunch of information. I think what you need is a button specifically the "Start a Hangout on Air" button. Also, all the links that was provided was also complete. Hope this could give you clue for the functionality you needed.

Comment: thanks, i've already seen this post and later came to know that hangouts is deprecated by google apis now