# Create a Live Event with a type of "Quick using Google Hangouts On Air" with API

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'd like to create a live broadcast event with a type of Quick (using Hangouts on Air for streaming) using the API.  I currently don't see a way to pass that in to the API.

Is that possible?

[image: screenshot]

I have been looking here to try to find a way to pass this in:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#resource

Comment: did u find an answer

Comment: did you find an answer x2?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979700/is-it-possible-to-create-event-of-type-quick-using-google-hangouts-on-air-us