# How can I create event of type Quick (using Google Hangouts On Air) using YouTube Live Streaming API?

Tags: youtube, stream, live

How can I create event of type Quick (using Google Hangouts On Air) using YouTube Live Streaming API? At the documentation of  Youtube Live Streaming API I couldn't find. Please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkHaF.png)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979700/is-it-possible-to-create-event-of-type-quick-using-google-hangouts-on-air-us